# Finding the Stationary Solution of an Advection-Diffusion PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, vector-analysis

Probably this is a trivial question.

I am trying to find stationary solutions (steady state solution) of
$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \nabla. (f(x) u) - D \nabla^2 u $$ 
where $f(x)$ is a vector valued function and D is a positive scaler.

So I want to solve:
$$   \nabla. (f(x) u) = D \nabla^2 u $$
 I will be thankful if you can point to out to references that deals with sort of problems.